# Web midi/audio: Why is onmidimessage not firing?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, web-midi

I am using the following code with cotejp's [webmidi](https://github.com/cotejp/webmidi) library to detect midi input events:

```
  WebMidi.enable(() => {
    WebMidi.inputs.forEach((input) => {
      input.addListener('noteon', 'all', (e)=>keys.noteOn(e));
      input.addListener('noteoff', 'all', (e)=>keys.noteOff(e));
      input.addListener('controlchange', 'all', this.controlChange);
    });
    resolve(WebMidi.inputs);
  });
```

For some reason this has stopped working. I couldn't figure out why so I tried creating an implementation which uses no libraries:

https://jsfiddle.net/kbmhwnrh/

All midi inputs are detected and opened successfully but onmidimessage does nothing. I have tried on multiple computers using multiple midi devices and have the same result. What am I missing?

Comment: Weird.  Works for me.  (Chrome 63.0.3239.70 on OSX.)

Comment: Works, too. Windows 10 (Chrome 63.0.3239.84 )

Comment: What is `keys` referring to in your code? It looks like you're trying to respond to a MIDI input message by sending a MIDI message somewhere else, presumably a MIDI output device? I took your code here and updated it to log to the console instead and it works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/k24Lx2uv/7/